# Subversion dumping last `n` revisions

Tags: svn

I'm trying to dump the last 500 revisions from an SVN repository (to reimport as new repo) using...

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repos > dump.dmp -r2000:HEAD
```

But the dump doesn't seem to stop and the dump file is reaching 3gb in size (a full dump 1:HEAD is only 600mb)

What am I doing wrong here?!

Answer (score 8):

Try the following:

```
svnadmin dump -r2000:HEAD /path/to/repos > dump.dmp
```