# How to dump last SVN revision?

Tags: svn

I am writing a batch file file to dump last SVN revision, compress it and upload it to OneDrive. I need to know how to dump last revision. I have seen this

[Subversion dumping last `n` revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106983/subversion-dumping-last-n-revisions)

but it is of no use to me as I don't get how it is working.

This command gives a specific revision, but I don't want to check and enter revision number every time. I want process to be automated.

svnadmin dump -r 164 C:\Users\rmheg\OneDrive\Antares_SVN\EmflexSVN > C:\trash\svn.dmp

Comment: The `HEAD` keyword is an alias for the latest revision. See [this document](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.keywords) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith **you must never run `svnadmin dump` with `-r HEAD`** option.

Comment: @ram you should give some context. Are you working on incremental backup?

Comment: Thanks for the correction @bahrep

Comment: @bahrep I want something like this: 
1. I have dumped the latest SVN which is at revision 165. I compress the file and upload it to OneDrive.
2. Now next day I am at revision 166. I also want to back this up and upload but I don't want previous versions dumped also to save space and time.